# Strange Undefined index error from deep string

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined

I know there is another question similar, but my problem look strange. The string on deep location (apologize if I am wrong, I am a newby.). I am running a PHP script, and keep getting errors like:

> Notice: Undefined index: default in D:\SERVER-MYWEB\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\MYTHEME\admin\library\options\options.php on line 843

Line 843 looks like this:

```
$value['default']['font-family']);
```

Here the code:

```
$family = isset($option['font']) && $option['font'] ? $option['font'] :
(isset($value['default']['font-family'])?$value['default']['font-family']:
$value['default']['font-family']);
```

Edit for full codes:

```
  <?php
 }

 function upfw_typography($value,$attr){
global $up_options,$up_fonts,$wpdb;

  $option = (isset($up_options->$value['id'])?$up_options->$value['id']:'');
if(!$option):
    global $default_options;
    $option = isset($value['value'])?$value['value']:array();
endif;

 $family = isset($option['font']) && $option['font'] ? $option['font'] : (isset($value['default']['font-family'])?$value['default']['font-family']:$value['default']['font-family']);
$fontsize = isset($option['fontsize']) && $option['fontsize'] ? $option['fontsize']: (isset($value['default']['font-size']) ? $value['default']['font-size'] : '');
$fontstyle = isset($option['fontstyle']) && $option['fontstyle'] ? $option['fontstyle']: (isset($value['default']['font-style']) ? $value['default']['font-style'] : '');   

    $lineheight = isset($option['lineheight']) && $option['lineheight'] ? $option['lineheight'] : (isset($value['default']['line-height']) ? $value['default']['line-height'] : '');
    $texttransform = isset($option['texttransform']) && $option['texttransform'] ? $option['texttransform'] : (isset($value['default']['text-transform']) ? $value['default']['text-transform'] : '');
    $fontweight = isset($option['fontweight']) && $option['fontweight'] ? $option['fontweight'] : (isset($value['default']['font-weight']) ? $value['default']['font-weight'] : '');
   $textdecoration = isset($option['textdecoration']) && $option['textdecoration'] ? $option['textdecoration'] : (isset($value['default']['text-decoration']) ? $value['default']['text-decoration'] : '');
    $textshadow = isset($option['textshadow']) && $option['textshadow'] ? $option['textshadow'] : (isset($value['default']['text-shadow']) ? $value['default']['text-shadow'] : '');
    $letterspacing = isset($option['letterspacing']) && $option['letterspacing'] ? $option['letterspacing'] : (isset($value['default']['letter-spacing']) ? $value['default']['letter-spacing'] : '');   
    $show_selector = (isset($value['show_selector']) ? $value['show_selector'] : '');
    $selector = isset($option['selector']) && $option['selector'] ? $option['selector'] : (isset($value['selector']) ? $value['selector'] : '');
    $fonts = $up_fonts; ?>
```

Is there a quick fix to resolve these error?
Really appreciate for any help

Thank you

Comment: You have to check first if `$value` does have an element with key `default` at all...

Comment: isset($value['default']['font-family']) ? $value['default']['font-family']: $value['default']['font-family'] doesn't make sense to me. So if not isset() you call it nonetheless?

Comment: @A-2-A apologize little confuse about that. Noted for future. Thank you.

Comment: no matter of apology, just a reminder to know. sorry if my words are bad.

Comment: I suggest you create a separate function with ```array_key_exists``` to handle all those ternary method,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
$family = (isset($option['font']) && $option['font'])? $option['font'] :((isset($value['default']))?((isset($value['default']['font-family']))?$value['default']['font-family']:"Arial"):"Arial");
```

Comment: got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in line 843

Comment: It's work, but make some other feature dissapear (font-weight) from the menu. Will check to fix. Your help almost finishing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should check for `default` index before using it:

```
if(isset($value['default'])) { 
//your code here
$family = isset($option['font']) && $option['font'] ? $option['font'] :
(isset($value['default']['font-family'])?$value['default']['font-family']:
$value['default']['font-family']);
}
```

Comment: `isset($value['default']['font-family']) ? $value['default']['font-family']:
$value['default']['font-family']` doesn't make sense to me. So if not isset() you call it nonetheless?

Comment: It,s work to fix the notify error, but can not save the input data. Thanks